# Watson NarrowBand Speech to Text not accepting ogg file

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, speech-to-text, watson

NodeJS app using ffmpeg to create ogg files from mp3 & mp4. If the source file is broadband, Watson Speech to Text accepts the file with no issues. If the source file is narrow band, Watson Speech to Text fails to read the ogg file. I've tested the output from ffmpeg and the narrowband ogg file has the same audio content (e.g. I can listen to it and hear the same people) as the mp3 file. Yes, in advance, I am changing the call to Watson to correctly specify the model and content_type. Code follows:

```
exports.createTranscript = function(req, res, next)
{ var _name = getNameBase(req.body.movie);
  var _type = getType(req.body.movie);
  var _voice = (_type == "mp4") ? "en-US_BroadbandModel" : "en-US_NarrowbandModel" ;
  var _contentType = (_type == "mp4") ? "audio/ogg" : "audio/basic" ;
  var _audio = process.cwd()+"/HTML/movies/"+_name+'ogg';
  var transcriptFile = process.cwd()+"/HTML/movies/"+_name+'json';

  speech_to_text.createSession({model: _voice}, function(error, session) {
    if (error) {console.log('error:', error);}
    else
      {
        var params = { content_type: _contentType, continuous: true,
         audio: fs.createReadStream(_audio),
          session_id: session.session_id
          };
          speech_to_text.recognize(params, function(error, transcript) {
            if (error) {console.log('error:', error);}
            else
              { fs.writeFile(transcriptFile, JSON.stringify(transcript), function(err) {if (err) {console.log(err);}});
                res.send(transcript);
              }
          });
      }
  });
}
```

`_type` is either mp3 (narrowband from phone recording) or mp4 (broadband)
`model: _voice` has been traced to ensure correct setting 
`content_type: _contentType` has been traced to ensure correct setting

Any ogg file submitted to Speech to Text with narrowband settings fails with `Error: No speech detected for 30s.` Tested with both real narrowband files and asking Watson to read a broadband ogg file (created from mp4) as narrowband. Same error message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Watson Speech to Text is confusing on this point. The documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?node#recognize_sessions_nonmp18) indicates that when using the narrowband model, that `content_type` should be set to `audio/basic`. That's incorrect. In this example, the inbound audio file is a narrowband file, but it's an ogg file, so `content_type` should still be `audio/ogg`. That single change resolves the problem.

Comment: audio/basic (Use audio in this format only with narrowband models.)

Comment: Hi Bob, I believe what the documentation says is "audio/basic (Use audio in this format only with narrowband models.)", which means that if you use this audio format then you can only use narrowband models.

Comment: Yes, Dani, that's the correct understanding of the sentence.  audio/basic can only be used with narrowband models, but narrowband models can be used with other types.

Comment: In this example, I'm creating an ogg file from an mp3 recording of a telephone conversation. The mp3, in this case, is narrowband, only 8kHz captured. Watson requires an ogg file for speech to text purposes, so the content_type MUST be audio/ogg even though the documentation indicates that audio.basic should be used when narrow band files are submitted. if you use audio/basic with and ogg file, the app will fail.